# Probability of occupied seats

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In a movie theater that can accommodate $n + k$ persons, $n$ persons are to be seated. What is the probability that $r ≤ n$ given seats are occupied?

My attempt:
Since there are total $n+k$ seats in which $n$ are occupied. So, we should pick $r$ from these $n$ seats. Thus probability should be $\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n+k}{r}}$. But my answer doesn't match with the correct one, $\frac{\binom{n+k-r}{n-r}}{\binom{n+k}{k}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your logic well, however if you understand mine, maybe you can see where you are going wrong.

So, this is what I am saying: Suppose that $r$ fixed seats are occupied. Then, $n+k-r$ seats in total are unoccupied. Since we have $n-r$ more people to be seated, the number of ways in which these $n-r$ people can be seated in the $n+k-r$ remaining seats is $\binom{n+k-r}{n-r}$.

Now, what is the sample space? The sample space is the number of ways in which $n$ people can be seated in $n+k$ seats, which is just $\binom{n+k}n = \binom{n+k}{(n+k) - n} = \binom{n+k}k$.

Hence the answer is $\dfrac{\binom{n+k-r}{n-r}}{\binom{n+k}k}$.

You have got your sample space also wrong , because your denominator does not match with mine. Please verify the sample space before you get back to me.

Comment: I accept that my logic was miserably wrong. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @sv_jan5 You are welcome.